Angular ControlValueAccessor using a nested form fails to update
I have a component, which implements ControlValueAccessor (via an abstract class which I used for other CVAs in my app) but it also uses a form, which has two more controls, one of which uses a CVA (via the same abstract class), too.
This is how it is supposed to work:
Parent form
  <-> Filter CVA 
     <-> Input CVA

Right now I can use the input CVA with a parent form and it works fine (can set from form value and can change its value), so:
Parent form
  <-> Input CVA

However when I use the intermediate layer, the Filter CVA component is only being updated from Input, but not from the parent form:
Parent form
  <- Filter CVA 
     <- Input CVA

but not like this
Parent form
  -> Filter CVA 
     -> Input CVA

After trying different ideas with the abstract class implementations and failing with all of them, I am now stuck. Why would a control value accessor fail to be patched from the parent form?
Here is the setup:
export class ParentComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
        private fb: UntypedFormBuilder
    ){
        super();

        this.form = this.fb.group({
            id: null,
            label: null,
            description: null,
            assignedTo: null,
            assignedTags: {tags:[45], state: 'or'}, // does not update underlying components!
            dueDate: [null, Validators.required],
            isTemplate: false,
            templateId: null,
            canComplete: true,
            notifyOnCompletion: false,
            isPrivate: false
        });
    }

    /** patches the form value ok, but will not update underlying components */
    public changeForm(): void {
         this.form.get('assignedTags').patchValue(null);
    }
}

Here is the filter component which seems to fail when setting the value from the outside form, but updates its value when the inner form is being updated
@Component({
    selector: 'tag-filter',
    templateUrl: './tag-filter.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tag-filter.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        {
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef( ()=> TagFilterComponent ),
        multi: true
        },
        {
        provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
        useExisting: forwardRef( ()=> TagFilterComponent ),
        multi: true
        }
    ],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TagFilterComponent extends AbstractInputComponent implements OnInit {

    @Output() public changed: EventEmitter<TagFilter> = new EventEmitter();

    public tags: Array<any> = [];

    public form: UntypedFormGroup;
    public STATES = {
        truthy: 'or',
        falsy: 'and'
    }

    private firstChange = true;

    constructor(
        private fb: UntypedFormBuilder,
        protected cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {
        super(cdr);
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            tags: [[]],
            state: 'or'
        });
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {

        this.form.valueChanges
            .subscribe((res: TagFilter) => {

                // this never gets triggered from outside, only from the inner form
                if ( res.tags.length < 2 ) {
                    res.state = 'or';
                    this.form.patchValue({state: 'or'}, {emitEvent: false});
                }
                const v = {tags: res.tags, state: res.state}
                if ( !this.firstChange || v.tags.length > 0 ) {
                    this.changed.emit(v);
                }
                this.firstChange = false;
                this.value = v;
            });

        if ( this.initialValue ) {
            this.form.patchValue(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initialValue)) );
        }
    }
}

Here is the HTML markup:
<div class="tag-filter">
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <tag-input
            formControlName="tags"></tag-input>
        <custom-toggle
            [state]="STATES.truthy"
            [stateFalse]="STATES.falsy"
            formControlName="state"></custom-toggle>
    </form>
</div>

And here is the Input component, which has a slightly different implementation for a CVA and works both ways:
@Component({
    selector: 'tag-input',
    templateUrl: './tag-input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tag-input.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        {
          provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
          useExisting: forwardRef( ()=> TagInputComponent ),
          multi: true
        },
        {
          provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
          useExisting: forwardRef( ()=> TagInputComponent ),
          multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class TagInputComponent extends AbstractInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator, OnInit, OnChanges {

    @Input() public formControlName: string;  
    @Output() public changed: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    public allTags: Array<LabelValue> = [];

    constructor(
        protected cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
        private tags: TagService,
        private controlContainer: ControlContainer
    ) {
        super(cdr);
    }
     
    /** needed for listening for control changes */
    public get control() {
        return this.controlContainer.control.get(this.formControlName);
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        TagService.newTags = [];
        this.readTags();
       
        this.control.valueChanges
            .subscribe(() => {
                /** triggers as expected */
                if ( this.control.pristine ) {
                    this.readTags();
                }
            });
    }
}

Any ideas, why the Filter Component is failing to be updated from outside?
Edit: Here is the abstract class I am using for all my custom controls. Also, after more debugging, I've caught that when Parent form sets control values, the writeValue is getting called, but value itself is never being set (as you see, it is a setter, calling writeValue afterwards)
@Directive()
export abstract class AbstractInputComponent implements OnChanges {

    /**
     * inner value
     */
    protected innerValue: unknown = null;
    protected innerErrors: AbstractInputErrors;

    /**
     * field label
     */
    @Input() public label: string;

    /**
     * required boolean
     */
    @Input() public required = false;


    /**
     * read only
     */
    @Input() public readonly = false;

    /**
     * placeholder to show
     * type allows numbers
     */
    @Input() public placeholder: any;

    @Input() public disabled = false;

    /**
     * control reference
     */
    @ViewChild('fieldInput') public fieldInput: NgModel;

    public isFocused = false;

    // infrastructure
    public registerOnChange(fn: any) { this.propagateChange = fn; }
    public registerOnTouched(fn: any) { this.propagateTouch = fn; }

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function, @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    public propagateChange = (_: any) => { };
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function, @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    public propagateTouch = (_: any) => { };

    constructor(
        protected cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
        ) { }

    /**
     * on changes hook
     */
    public ngOnChanges(): void {
        if ( this.readonly ) {
            this.propagateChange(this.value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * input events
     */
    public onFocus(): void {
        this.isFocused = true;
    }

    public onBlur(): void {
        this.isFocused = false;
        this.propagateTouch(true);
    }

    /**
     * value accessor setter and getter
     */
    public get value(): any {
        return this.innerValue;
    };

    @Input() public set value(value: any) {
        if ( value !== undefined ) {
            this.writeValue(value);
            this.propagateChange(this.innerValue);
            this.propagateTouch(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * value accessor implementation
     * @param value
     */
    public writeValue(value: any): void {
        if (value !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = this.normalize(value);
        }
    }

    public setDisabledState(state: boolean): void {
        this.disabled = state;
    }

    /**
     * shows asterisk for required fields (without showing an error message first)
     */
    public get showRequiredHint(): boolean {
        if ( this.required && !this.errors && !this.readonly ) {
            if ( this.fieldInput && this.hasNoValue(this.fieldInput.control) ) {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * setting errors
     */
    public get errors(): AbstractInputErrors {
        return this.innerErrors;
    }

    public set errors( err: AbstractInputErrors ) {
        if ( this.fieldInput ) {
            if ( err ) {
                this.innerErrors = err;
            }
            this.fieldInput.control.setErrors(err);
        }
    }

    /**
     * validation
     * @param c
     */
    public validate(c: UntypedFormControl): unknown | null {
        this.innerErrors = (this.readonly) ? null : this.customValidate(c);
        this.errors = this.innerErrors;
        return this.errors;
    }

    protected abstract normalize(value)
    protected abstract customValidate(control)
    protected abstract hasNoValue(value)
}


Your component NOT implements ControlValueAccesor (or you don't add the code in your question). Do you want to use viewProvider (a simple component) instead of a custom FormControl)? See this SO to get the different approaches
